# Terminating a Form while COM DataReceived Event keeps fireing. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety, serial-port

I'm currently having a problem, which seems to be related to closing a Form, while a scale, which is connected through a Serial Connection keeps sending data (about 3 packages per sek).

I handle new data over the DataReceived-Event (handling itself might be uninteresting for this issue, since I'm just matching data) Keep an eye on the COM_InUse variable and the allowFireDataReceived check.):

```
    private void COMScale_DataReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (allowFireDataReceived)
        {
            //set atomar state
            COM_InUse = true;

            //new scale:
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.ScaleId == 1)
            {
                strLine = COMScale.ReadTo(((char)0x2).ToString());
                //new scale:
                Regex reg = new Regex(Constants.regexScale2);
                Match m = reg.Match(strLine);
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    strGewicht = m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[2];
                    double dblComWeight;
                    double.TryParse(strGewicht, out dblComWeight);
                    dblScaleActiveWeight = dblComWeight / 10000;
                    //add comma separator and remove zeros
                    strGewicht = strGewicht.Substring(0, 1) + strGewicht.Substring(1, 2).TrimStart('0') + strGewicht.Substring(3);
                    strGewicht = strGewicht.Insert(strGewicht.Length - 4, ",");

                    //write to textbox
                    ThreadSafeSetActiveScaleText(strGewicht);

                    COMScale.DiscardInBuffer();
                    //MessageBox.Show(dblScaleActiveWeight.ToString(), "dblScaleActiveWeight");
                }

            }
            //free atomar state
            COM_InUse = false;
        }
    }
```

The COM_InUse variable is a global bool and "tells" if there is a current process of handling data.
The allowFireDataReceived is also a global bool and if set to false will lead to no extra handling of the data which has been sended.

My problem now is the following:

It seems that Eventhandling is a separate Thread, which leads to a deadlock on klicking the Cancel-Button since the COM_InUse will never turn to false, even if the Event was handled (see end of COMScale_DataReceived, where COM_InUse is set to false). 
While setting allowFireDataReceived = false works perfectly (no handling any more), as I said: the while loop will not terminate.

```
    private void bScaleCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        allowFireDataReceived = false;
        while (COM_InUse)
        {
            ;
        }
        if (!COM_InUse)
        {
            ret = 1;
            SaveClose();
        }
    }
```

When I comment out the while-block I have to click twice on the button, but it works without a crash. Since this very user unfriendly, I'm searching for an alternative way to safely close the window.

Info: 
Simply closing (without checking if the COM-Data was processed) lead to a fatal crash.

So, maybe someone can explain to me what exactly causes this problem or can provide a solution to this. (Maybe one would be to trigger the Cancel-Clicking Event again, but that is very ugly)

Greetings!

I count on you :)

//edit:
Here is the current code of

```
    private void ThreadSafeSetActiveScaleText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.lScaleActive.InvokeRequired)
        {   
            SafeActiveScaleTextCallback d = new SafeActiveScaleTextCallback(ThreadSafeSetActiveScaleText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.lScaleActive.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   ThreadSafeSetActiveScaleText(strGewicht);
```

Yes, the DataReceived event runs on a threadpool thread.  You already knew that, you wouldn't have called it "ThreadSafe" otherwise.  What we can't see is what is inside this method.  But given the outcome, it is highly likely that you are using Control.Invoke().

Which is going to cause deadlock when you loop on COM_InUse in code that runs on the UI thread.  The Control.Invoke() method can only complete when the UI thread has executed the delegate target method.  But the UI thread can only do that when it is idle, pumping the message loop and waiting for Windows messages.  And invoke requests.  It cannot do this while it looping inside the Click event handler.  So Invoke() cannot complete.  Which leaves the COM_InUse variable for ever set to true.  Which leaves the Click event handler forever looping.  Deadlock city.

The exact same problem occurs when you call the SerialPort.Close() method, the port can only be closed when all events have been processed.

You will need to fix this by using Control.BeginInvoke() instead.  Make sure the data is still valid by the time the delegate target starts executing.  Pass it as an argument for example, copying if necessary.

Closing the form while the scale is unrelentingly sending data is in general a problem.  You'll get an exception when you invoke on a disposed form.  To fix this, you'll need to implement the FormClosing event handler and set e.Cancel to true.  And unsubscribe the DataReceived event and start a timer.  Make the Interval a couple of seconds.  When the timer Ticks, you can close the form again, now being sure that all data was drained and no more invokes can occur.

Also note that calling DiscardInBuffer() is only good to randomly lose data.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping to be able to clean some of the data that has been sent by the scale while processing one data-package (Regex matching and stuff) via DiscardInBuffer().
Well sounds like I there is no true simple way to handle that problem. 

Btw: As I said, when allowFireDataReceived is set to false closing the scale connection works without problems.

Comment: Sounds like you only read the last paragraph in the answer.  So are you using Invoke?

Comment: yes, I do use Invoke (code added in first post). 
And no, I did read your whole post. Maybe I got you wrong. I'll give StartInvoke() a try.
//edit:
So basically I have to use BeginInvoke() instead of Invoke(). Is there anything I have to take care of? Like EndInvoke()?

Comment: Wow, what an earth is the point of asking for an answer if you are not going to read it?  Good luck with StartInvoke :)

Comment: Sorry, didnt mean to offend you... I really read your answer and I think I got it. It's just that I have to learn all that by myself and sometimes I'm not sure if I got it right, thats why I was asking twice. C# is totally new to me and I'm doing my best to understand what is happening. 

Thanks for your help